# Summing the number in a different sheet equal to a specific cell

Tags: excel

I want to take this information in one sheet

[image: Original]

and total up the number in this new sheet for each auditor

[image: New]

But I keep getting 0's

I am using this Formula

```
=SUM('COO Lines Count'!A1:B15=A2) in the new sheet
```

Comment: Do you want the **total** or the **average** ???

Comment: All i am trying to do is grab that number from the first sheet for the auditor's in the new sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUMIF()` is what you need:

```
=SUMIF('COO Lines Count'!A$1:A$15,A2,'COO Lines Count'!B$1:B$15)
```